# Wait on loading SharePoint Webparts - timing issue

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm experiencing what appears to be a timing issue when loading a few webparts in the same SharePoint 2007 site.

Currently I have a few webparts on my site, all aligned vertically aligned.  I want the bottom-most webpart to load last, because it has a component that will be rendered to do a jQuery `.offset().top` (which gets the top left position of the component at the time the code is executed).  Currently, the component appears at an incorrect place every time I reload the page.  The only time it is at the correct place is when there are no other webparts above it.

For example:

WebPartWithComponent the first one on the page:

```
WebPartWithComponent <-- component rendered here correctly.
WebPart1
WebPart2
WebPart3
```

Other webparts in front of the WebPartWithComoonent on the page:

```
Webpart1
Webpart2 <-- component rendered here instead.
WebpartWithComponent <-- this is where the component should be rendered
Webpart4
```

Are there any ways to ensure the webpart with the component to load last, or start to load when the other webparts have completed loading, or wait at a particular point in the code until the other webparts have completed loading?

The webparts are rendered in jQuery (js) files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use jQuery ready function in your last web part?

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //do your stuff
});
```

Or if you have that, setup some kind of tracking array in your web parts:

```
if(typeof(gWebParts)=="undefined") {
gWebParts = new Array()
}
gWebParts[gWebParts.length] = someobject
```

Then when they have loaded, set some variable

```
gWebParts[i].loaded = true
```

And in your final webpart, setup a timer

```
setInterval(function() {
   if(gWebParts all loaded) {
      clearInterval()
      //do your stuff
   }
}, 250)
```